Querying jsonb column with nested objects and array of values in PostgreSQL?
I have a jsonb column with data like this:
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "type": "weekdays",
            "values": [
                3,
                5
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "dates",
            "values": [
                "2024-01-01",
                "2024-01-02",
                "2024-01-03"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

What would a SELECT statement look like if I:

Wanted to get all records WHERE ( rules[0].type.weekdays ).values CONTAINS 3:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsonb_column->>'rules'->0->'type'->'weekdays' : [the-result]->values = ANY ('{3}'::int[]);


Wanted to get all records WHERE ( rules[0].type.dates ).values CONTAINS '2024-01-02' (date-string):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsonb_column->>'rules'->0->'type'->'dates' ? [the-result]->values = ANY ('{"2024-01-03"}'::date[?]);

So, basically I need to find the object of a certain type AND THEN figure out whether that objects values contain what I'm looking for.
PSEUDO CODE:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsonb_column->rules[ how-to-iterate-array? ]->type = 'weekdays' AND [from-that-resulting-object]->>values CONTAIN 3;


could you add example input and example output, with, let's say, one row in the input which should appear in the output and another row in the input which should be filtered out?

I believe you're looking for json paths which let you express such conditions. In your case, that would be
WHERE jsonb_column @@ '$.rules[*] ? (@.type == "weekdays") .values[*] == 3'
WHERE jsonb_column @@ '$.rules[*] ? (@.type == "dates") .values[*] == "2024-01-03"'

or
WHERE jsonb_column @? '$.rules[*] ? (@.type == "weekdays" && @.values[*] == 3)'
WHERE jsonb_column @? '$.rules[*] ? (@.type == "dates" && @.values[*] == "2024-01-03")'


you can use jsonpath and jsonb_path_exists for that:
select *
from (values
    ('{ "rules": [
        {"type": "weekdays", "values": [3, 5]},
        {"type": "dates", "values": ["2024-01-01", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-03"]}
    ]}'::jsonb),
    ('{ "rules": [
        {"type": "weekdays", "values": [5, 4]},
        {"type": "dates", "values": ["2024-01-01", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-03"]}
    ]}'::jsonb)
) as a(data)
where
    jsonb_path_exists(a.data, '$.rules[*] ? (@.type == "weekdays").values[*] ? (@ == 3)')

returns only one row:
{"rules": [{"type": "weekdays", "values": [3, 5]}, {"type": "dates", "values": ["2024-01-01", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-03"]}]}


OK, thanks. I'll see if I can fit this into my brains limited capacity, as it's pretty cryptic to decipher ... I'll give it a go and get back.

you can take a look at documentation of jsonpath in postgresql (the link in the answer), it's quite good
